# How to determine if $f(n) = \binom{n}{2} - (n!)^{\frac{1}{n}} + n$ is an increasing function or not?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, inequality

$\forall n\ge 2, n \in \mathbb N$ ; define $f$ as

$$f(n) =  \binom{n}{2} - (n!)^{\frac{1}{n}} + n.$$

I have easily proved that $f(n) > 0$ in the given domain using A.M.-G.M. inequality.

However, I ran a program for curiosity and observed that $f$ is increasing for first $1000$ natural numbers (obviously except for $n = 1)$.

I want to determine if this is true or not for all $n \in \mathbb N$ that $f$ is an increasing function. Can you give me a hint?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Here's a guide for [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Please, use it to improve your your knowledge so you can write proper MathJax. For example, use `\forall` to get $\forall$ instead the character ∀, or use `\binom{x}{y}` to get $\binom{x}{y}$.

Comment: Maybe you need to apply induction or assume to values $n_1$, $n_2$ where the function value is the same. However, all these are very hard.

Comment: @jjagmath Okay thanks. I did searched for mathJax equivalent on google but couldn't find it directly. Thanks for link.

Comment: @NoChance I have only always used induction for proving simple equalities , let far go inequalities and if they are hard. Anyway, thanks for another method. I hope I'll learn it in future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have $n! = 1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdots n < n\cdot n\cdots n = n^n$ or $(n!)^{\frac{1}{n}} < n$ or $n - (n!)^{\frac{1}{n}} > 0$ hence,

$$
f(n+1) = {n+1\choose 2} - (n+1)!^{\frac{1}{n+1}} + (n+1) > {n+1\choose 2} = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} \tag 1
$$

Also

$$
f(n) < {n\choose 2} + n = \frac{n(n-1)}{2} + n \tag 2
$$

Now,
$
f(n+1) - f(n) >  \textit{something less than $f(n+1)$} -  \textit{something more than $f(n)$}
$

Hence
$$
f(n+1) - f(n) > \frac{n(n+1)}{2} - \frac{n(n-1)}{2} - n = 0
$$

or $f(n+1) > f(n)$.

Comment: How did you combine the two inequalities if the inequality operators are not same ?Thanks !

Comment: @An_Elephant Because $f(n+1) - f(n)$ will always be greater than $ \textit{something less than $f(n+1)$} -  \textit{something more than $f(n)$}$

Comment: @An_Elephant They are the same after you multiply the second by $-1$: $$f(n+1) > \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$ and $$-f(n) > -\frac{n(n-1)}{2}-n$$ Then just add both inequalities.

Comment: Typo : $n.n....n = \color{blue}{n^n}$

Comment: @An_Elephant Try to keep your comments genderless.

Comment: @jjagmath I'm sorry for mistake. I'll delete it immediately. ( I usually say "sir" to teachers ).